# Render facelets programmatically (or how to use facelets to render an email)

Tags: email, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I would like to use facelets as markup engine to send emails. Those emails can be generated in the context of an HttpServeletRequest or outside of it (I.e. in another thread).

From what I've been reading, the only way to do it is "hacking" the request (https://gist.github.com/vvasabi/1087206 ), which has several inconviniences... it can only be done inside a request thread and it does not work correctly in an ajax request (tried with myfaces 2.2.8).

Another way would be having a idempotent URL which renders the markup, but this also has a few inconviniences: any intermediate data has to be passed as request parameters or initialized in a viewAction, which is not always easy, sessionId must be mocked up...

Is there an easy way to do it or should I just stay away from facelets and use another markup engine to render emails?

(myfaces 2.2.8)

Comment: Upcoming OmniFaces 2.2 adds new utility methods for that in `Components` class: `String mailHtml = Components.encodeHtml(Components.buildView("/WEB-INF/mail-template.xhtml"));` Does this satisfy your needs? Must be done when  `FacesContext` is available, obviously.

Comment: I think it does, but how should I add some params?... Some CID strings for images? Should I set them in request scope and then restore the request after that?

Comment: Just set some bean properties the usual way. It runs in same request but builds in a different faces context.

Comment: Ok, that looks good, I'll try and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having some problems with this. Used in an ajax request it does not work, it renders: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><partial-response id="j_id__v_0">.... and the ajax response is empty

Comment: Thanks for feedback, will look at it.

Comment: Used in a non-ajax request, the problem is that it renders the js/css dependencies from the parent page. IE: <script type="text/javascript" src="/travelc/javax.faces.resource/primefaces/jquery/jquery-plugins.js"></script>... (I'm not using any primefaces tag in the email, and I also removed a headRenderer that was including all dependencies). And when the page reloads those dependencies are not loaded